# jquery won't load in footer

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, wp-register-script

I wanted to move jquery to the site's footer, but that doesn't work. I've tried it with the following code.

As you can see, I have a couple of another scripts and they load correctly on the footer. Only jquery won't work.

```
//This adds our JavaScript Files
function wel_adding_scripts() {

wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', '', '2.1.1', true); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

wp_register_script('jquery.mixitup', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery.mixitup.min.js','','1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery.mixitup');

wp_register_script('headroom', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/headroom.min.js','','1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('headroom');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wel_adding_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if any script in the header at all needs jQuery then it will bump it to header, regardless if it's changed to be enqueued for footer.

So while changing it to be queued for footer makes sense it rarely works out when a lot of script stuff is going on.

Comment: That's a great point!

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the problem](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script#Notes)

> If you try to register or enqueue an already registered handle with
>   different parameters, the new parameters will be ignored. Instead, use
>   wp_deregister_script() and register the script again with the new
>   parameters.

You will have to deregister jquery first, the register it again, but becareful because the empty string isn't what you should put in the place of the `deps` parameter. IT should be an empty array.

Like this:

```
     wp_register_script('jquery',
 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
     array() , '2.1.1', true);
```

Comment: Hi, i have deregistered it as you cann see it at the code. Now i have put empty array() and still no changes.

Comment: Also, change the priority in the `add_action` , I think it should be 11, but read the docs if that doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, but what shall i read? I've add the priority 11 and it still does not work. I have read many Tutorials about this and i also read the wp_register_scripts documentation. I can't figure it out, why it won't work.

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin?

Comment: No, this is a clean WordPress only for Theme Testing.

Comment: Do you have `WP_DEBUG` set to true? If not, turn it on from the wp-config.php file. I don't know which tutorials you read, but check this one out [http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/how-to-properly-use-jquery-scripts-in-wordpress/](http://devotepress.com/wordpress-coding/how-to-properly-use-jquery-scripts-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Ok i've tried it to do it with this tutorial. If i set '$in_footer' to 'false' then it will bump jquery to the header.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I have do it the right way, all the time. Now i found, that jquery was deregistered at the themes header.php file. I have deleted it and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function your_function() {
    echo '<p>This is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_function');
?>
```

You can use this hook. This is used to load the script in the footer try it let me know for any doubts.

Comment: Don't use `wp_footer` to load scripts. If you properly enqueue/register a script and use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook properly, which is the correct hook that you **should use** your scripts should be loaded in the footer

Comment: @pieter Goosen I didn't get you could you explain me clearly why we want to use wp_wnqueue_scripts?

Comment: Read [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) :-)